# NativeScript SideKick Android Cloud Build failed Invalid Filename

Tags: android, nativescript

My app is compiling ok from cloud for iOS Release (not debug) 
When I'm trying to do the same for Android, I get the "Invalid Filename" error, just after asking for the password of my certificate which I have previously created :

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore release.keystore -alias Selector -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

I don't know if any correlation between the app names and the command is needed. As a matter of fact, I'm not sure at all if the error is really related with the certificate.

Any idea?

Comment: The certificate is working fine with Adobe Phonegap Build, so I think the problem is my Nativescript app config...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now working, don't know how, I think it was the perfect storm between Typescript not compiling properly to JS, Graggle not working fine etc...